# numpy float64s as keys to a dict

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

If I have a dict whose keys are numpy float64 numbers, how do I can access them by key value?

```
>>> keys = np.arange(0, 0.5, 0.05, dtype=np.float64)
>>> keys
    array([...,  0.3 ,  ...])

    # The following creates a dicionary lookup table
    # data[x] = exp(x) for all x in keys

>>> data = {key: np.exp(key) for key in keys}
>>> data[0.3]
    KeyError: 0.3
>>> data[np.float64(0.3)]
    KeyError: 0.29999999999999999
>>> data.keys()
[..., 0.30000000000000004, ...]
```

Do numpy floats even have the capability to be used as keys to a dict?

Comment: Using floats as dict keys is brave...

Comment: Using floats as dict keys is semantically how one thinks of a mapping between one value and another. The real calculation I am doing is not the sort of thing you want to have to do each time you want a value. Is there a more elegant way to create a map?

Comment: Why not just store the results as an array?

Comment: "The real calculation I am doing is not the sort of thing you want to have to do each time you want a value."  What is the calculation you're doing?  If you're already using numpy, then you should try to take advantage of numpy's vectorization.

Comment: Sure you can use it, but you should be aware of the problems and since you just ran into it... I could also say using arange for float is bad, the doc suggests linspace, and linspace in fact would probably do better here (though you still should be careful)

Comment: Instead of thinking of it as a key lookup, think of it as an interpolation problem.

Comment: If you use `linspace(0, 0.5, 11)` instead of `arange(0, 0.5, 0.05)`, can you instead use the index in the interval [0, 11) as the key instead of the actual float? From the index, you can easily calculate the float using `linspace(0, 0.5, 11)[index]`.

Comment: "If I have a dict whose keys are numpy float64 numbers, how do I can access them by key value?" By using the exact same value as the key. The only problem is that "exact same" is a tricky concept with floats. Even besides the representation/rounding errors, if you had actual _real_ numbers, they would _also_ be tricky as keys, because it strongly implies you want an (uncountably!) infinite number of keys, which you don't have the memory for. That's why DSM's comment is the key here. Build a function, or build a `dict`-like Mapping class that wraps it up for you, but don't use `dict`.

Comment: P.S., for an interpolation-based `dict`-like Mapping class, there's another question somewhere on SO where someone built one, on top of `bintrees` or one of the other BST implementations, that you might want to search for. (Although IIRC the question might have been closed because he just posted reasonable code without any question attached to it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment, "The real calculation I am doing is not the sort of thing you want to have to do each time you want a value. Is there a more elegant way to create a map?"

This is a standard problem, and the general solution is known as a **Lookup Table** or LUT.  The are many implementations, with and without numpy and scipy, that you can find by searching.  [Here's](http://www.shocksolution.com/2008/12/a-lookup-table-for-fast-python-math/) a solution that uses scipy's interpolation methods.

As others have said, using floating point numbers as dictionary keys is problematic.  Plus, using a LUT, you can also interpolate between two pre-calculated solutions, which can increase accuracy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For various reasons described in comments and the other answer, this will often be a bad idea, especially for "production quality" source code. However, if we're just working on a quick and dirty python script, it can sometimes be useful to try it anyway.

One solution that seems fairly reliable so far to me is to use the `round()` function to make sure that all the numbers in `keys` are identical to numbers that we as humans would type with only a handful of decimals. For example (using `Python 3.6`):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> keys = [round(key, 4) for key in np.arange(0, 0.5, 0.05, dtype=np.float64)]
>>> keys
    [0.0, 0.050000000000000003, 0.10000000000000001, 0.14999999999999999, 0.20000000000000001, 0.25, 0.29999999999999999, 0.34999999999999998, 0.40000000000000002, 0.45000000000000001]
>>> data = {key: np.exp(key) for key in keys}
>>> data[0.3]
    1.3498588075760032
>>> data[np.float64(0.3)]
    1.3498588075760032
>>> data.keys()
    dict_keys([0.0, 0.050000000000000003, 0.10000000000000001, 0.14999999999999999, 0.20000000000000001, 0.25, 0.29999999999999999, 0.34999999999999998, 0.40000000000000002, 0.45000000000000001])
```

The keys can still have lots of decimals due to internal (floating-point) representation, but at least they'll be consistent with new floats that us humans would type, like `0.3`.